Is there any relation between load delay and render delay on Largest content paint on Lighthouse?
So I was trying to optimize image loading. As per the lighthouse report, the Largest Contentful Paint element is in red mark and needs improvement.
So The data looked like this:

As you can see the load delay was taking the longest time out of all the components inside LCP. So to improve that, I thought of preloading the image
<head>
  <link rel="preload" fetchpriority="high"  href="{{imageUrl}}" as="image">
</head>

And it did improve the load Delay significantly. However, now the render delay increases almost by the same proportion and hence there's no net gain on the performance report and LCP remains in red. How are these related to each other? What else can I do here for a net gain in performance?

Am I doing something incorrectly?

your images are going to be much bigger than the page itself, so the parse will finish parsing well before your image source has even downloaded. Preloading has no effect on LCP. Use a smaller image, or use a smaller initial image and then asynchronously swap it out for a higher resolution image once the page is ready for enhancement.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans By smaller you mean smaller in size? I actually did that (download image that's half the size). It didn't have much effect

but what's the difference between the page itself and image? Because a half size image when the full image is a 1MB jpeg is still "ridiculously huge" and will dominate your LCP. But note that you can get lost in image optimization, so remember that your goal isn't a perfect lighthouse score, but "does the page load fast enough for your users".

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Hmm the image size is around 225kb so I tried downloading half of its size on local. You can see here:
https://careers.innovage.com/ Btw coming to that question, I get the load time reduce, why does the render delay appear to increase and vice versa?
